# Transformation between nearby tangent planes

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry, geodesics

This question is kinda long, but the picture is quite clear.

[image]

*Question*: Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold, $p$ a point on $M$, $U$ an open neighborhood of $0\in T_pM$ such that $exp_p|_U$ is a diffeomorphism, $X$ a vector in $U$, $q:= exp_p(X)$. Now since $U$ is open, there is an open neighborhood $V$ of $X \in T_pM$ so that $exp_p|_V$ is also a diffeomorphism. However, there is another diffeomorphism $exp_q|W$ for some neighborhood $W$ of $0\in T_qM$.

**In short**, there **must** be a natural identification around $X \in T_pM$ and $0\in T_qM$. How could we say about this identification? My guess is there should be an explicit formula involving Levi-Civita connection induced by the metric $g$.

*Application 1*: This should also give a formula for $exp(A+B)$ for Lie groups (with metric). Notice that this is **not** the Hausdorff-Campbell formula, which describes a formula for $exp(A)exp(B)$.

Comment: When you edit your post you will see a row of pictures.  Between the curly braces and the "chain" there is the button to upload pictures.  I would like to suggest editing your post as well, as it is a little difficult to follow.

Comment: Thank you! I have added a picture for it.

Comment: While this isa reasonable question, I think it ks more suited to math.stackexchange.

Comment: Is there a way to move this question to math.stackexchange? I tried to post it again, but the system did not allow due to duplicity.

Comment: I suppose there will be some sort of functional relation but I'm not certain if you can expect much beyond general nonsense.  For example, if the Riemann manifold is not analytic you should expect the formula will also not be analytic.  If you don't want something like a power series expansion, what kind of description would you want?